# Efficient way to get total unique visitor count GAE Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ip

I want to get a total unique visitor count for a page on my Google App Engine python app.

Right now, on every request to the page, I call `self.request.remote_addr.get()` to get the user's IP address, and I have a entity property with a list of all IP addresses. I loop through this property and check if the user's IP address is already in the list. If not, I add the user's IP address.

This obviously seems like a very inefficient way to achieve a total count of unique visitors.

Would really appreciate it if someone can give me a suggestion on how to achieve this in a more efficient manner using less resources?

Comment: Do you need the data to be real time, or is it just something for your own info?

Comment: It's a user-generated content app and I want to show the total number of views (or unique viewers) on the page. So does not have to be real-time per se but I am displaying the number to users.

Comment: use google analytics?

Comment: @marcadian If I only want this feature I'm guessing MeLight's solution would be more lightweight/efficient?

Comment: Depends, google analytics just few lines of javascript included in your page and have some sort of dashboard / basic reporting, I'll use this if this is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is export your App Engine logs to BigQuery (on developers dahsboard, open Logging > Exports. More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export)). The App Engine logs save the ip of the visitor, and the export to BigQuery will put it in a neat, queriable [huge] table.

From there you can run SQLish queries on humongous amounts of data rather quickly (seconds) and cheaply. You could run a uniques query (something along the lines of: `select * from dataset group by ip`) every hour or so, so your data will be relatively fresh.